# process.exit() finished with status: 'connection error'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

> I am trying to exit the function if the data is found in the firestore

```
    var flag= admin.firestore().collection('video').doc(thumbnailName);
    var getDoc = flag.get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
          console.log('exit process');// data found in firestore exit frm here
      process.exit();     
return null;// doesnt work here   
          } 
          else {
            console.log('create data in firestore');// do some work here
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });
```

return null doesnt seem to work inside the  then scope

the error i get is

> process.exit() finished with status: 'connection error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `process.exit()` and your `return null` and only call `resolve()` which is a special promise method that will end the current promise execution.

Comment: i get an error like this: 
 resolve is not defined
    at flag.get.then.doc

Comment: You can try changing your logic and only handling the case where doc doesn't exist like `if(!doc.exists) { // do something }` and avoid using the else

Comment: i want it to terminate right away just as return null; works

Comment: You can always use `return` without arguments and finish current function execution